# Quick doubt on a negation of a statement.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

The statement I want to negate is: there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $f(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in A$ where $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $x \ne x_0$

The negation I think is correct is: for all $\delta > 0$ there exist an $x \in A$ s.t. $f(x) \le 0$ where $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $x \ne x_0$.

But a friend of mines says that it is: there does not exist a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $f(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in A$ where $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $x \ne x_0$.

Are we both right? In any case could you kindly explain which is right and which wrong and for what reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. Your friend's negation only puts a "not" in front of the entire sentence, though, which is not useful when you want to use a negation in a proof. The negation you wrote is more useful when you want to use the statement in a proof, because you have thoroughly negated the entire structure of the formula.